# Tab Bar hides CustomView containing CollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

[image]I have created a separate `customView` class containing collection view along with its `Xib`, and then i try to load this `customView` to one of the controller's view which is connected to a `Tab Bar Controller`. The view gets loaded perfectly but the last item of collection view is hidden behind the tab bar.
It would be great to have a solution for that.

My customView looks as [image]

Comment: What do you think would fit in this case?

Comment: when you use ContentView Controller The SubView of Main View are hiding , becouse you bring another controller in front , bringSubView to front

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let bottomOffset: CGFloat = (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)! // this your tabbar height you can replace with static number eg. 44
        collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, bottomOffset, 0)
    }
```

Comment: KKRocks here ;)

Answer (score 0):

set

```
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: self is for whom? collectionView or customView

Comment: Its `ViewController`. Put that in `ViewDidLoad` or `ViewWillAppear` of `VIewController`

Comment: It works, but In this case the translucent effect goes off

Comment: Set `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES` will solve that

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck Under Bottom Bars..

It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: It works, but In this case the translucent effect goes off